# How to put first div with max height possible?

Tags: css

I have a div ".container" with two divs: first ".blue" and second ".green".
I got my green div fixed to the bottom-0, but I need to put the first div blue to backboard the green div.

http://jsfiddle.net/washington_guedes/k959kmqd/

---

css:

```
.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.blue{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #acf;
}
.green{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #bfb;
}
```

---

html:

```
<!-- some divs before -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="blue">Blue</div>
    <div class="green">Green</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want something liket this? http://jsfiddle.net/k959kmqd/1/

Comment: or like this? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/neoaptt/rk6qtput/)

Comment: What do you mean by backboard? as a background?

Comment: if you want the the blue `div` to take available height use `calc`[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/k959kmqd/2/)

Comment: And if you want it to take all height (including the height that exists behind the green div), you can add use `html, body, .container, .blue { height: 100%; }` You can test by setting `.green`'s `opacity` to `0.5`.

Comment: This is a pretty unclear question...I don't even know what answer is he expecting...

Answer (score 0):

You could set both div to be absolute position and then play with whatever you need to do:

```
.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.blue,
.green {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 250px;
}

.blue{    
    background-color: #bbf;
}

.green{ 
    background-color: #bfb;
    top: 250px;
}
```

Divs in top of each other http://jsfiddle.net/vfpzbj9q/

Divs overlapping http://jsfiddle.net/wkkyoz0h/